# Visual Studio 2015 Won't Link GLFW

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw

I've been following the tutorials on [learnopengl.com](http://learnopengl.com), but when I tried to compile a program with GLFW I get this error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glfw3.lib'
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
std::cout << "HelloWorld" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I know I have the "Include Directories" correct and "Additional Dependencies", because a) I double checked and b) It doesn't have any problems with glew

Comment: You also need to point the "Library Directories" to where glfw3.lib is located.

Comment: Thank you! You can post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to point the "Library Directories" to where `glfw3.lib` is located.